# Add validation to accept WMV file

Tags: php, symfony

I need to add validation to only accept some files for upload in our website. These are the following : FLV, MP4, AVI and WMV.

Validation is working fine for all above extensions but it's not working for WMV files. I have added video/x-ms-wmv mime type to allow WMV file.

Here is my code:

```
     /**
     * @Assert\File(
     * mimeTypes = {"video/x-flv", "video/mp4", "video/x-msvideo", "video/x-ms-wmv"},
     * mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid video file ie(flv, mp4, avi, wmv)"
     * )
     */
```

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem too, try `audio/x-ms-wmv`, maybe it help you.

Comment: He is asking for `video` not for `audio`